# Flutter app can not execute http function in VS code

Tags: flutter, dart, http, visual-studio-code

I have this furture in my flutter app which is just to fetch the response from the web pages from the list. When I start the app via the console "flutter run" or Android Studio it executes the function correctly.
With VS Code since today this error comes up:

```
address: null
message: Failed host lookup: 'www.google.com'
osError: OSError (OS Error: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.
, errno = 11004)
port: null
```

vs code version: 1.81.1

App was run as a Windows app and on physical devices.
Future:

```
Future<void> fetchGoogle() async {
    List<String> urls = [
      'https://www.google.com',
      'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
    ];
    for (var url in urls) {
      try {
        print("request to $url");
        final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          print('$url response received!');
        } else {
          print('Failed to fetch from $url.');
        }
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        print('Error (${e.toString()}) to fetch from $url.');
      }
    }
  }
```

I created a new project, rebooted computer, VS code removed all extensions and reinstalled. No success.

Comment: Have you looked up at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted?rq=2

Comment: yes but it dosent help... it is not a plattform spezific error. whenn i run the app for android in android studio it works!

Comment: Maybe it works without `www`, just `google.com`?